# Please help me understand what 'list<Msg*>' is

Tags: c++, list, dictionary, vector, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string.h>

struct message
{
    int id;
    char mesg[100]; 
}; 

int main()    
{
    struct message Msg;
    Msg.id=111;
    strcpy(Msg.mesg," am fine");
    list<Msg*> l1;
}
```

I need this `l1` list size is not empty. but when I compile this code it is showing an error.

Comment: `list<Msg *> l1;` ==> `std::list<Msg *> l1;`

Comment: hello sir/madam, actually i need l1.size() value is not empty  but if i run this code means i shown only empty

Comment: @mohan the list is empty, because you have not put any values into the list, such as with its `push_back()` method, eg: `l1.push_back(&Msg);`

Comment: Unrelated: Is there a reason you're using C-strings in C++? What's wrong with `Msg.mesg = " am fine";`?

Comment: no.. for inserting the value, am using C-string

Answer (score 3):

in c++ for a list you can use the `push_back()` function

the reason your list is empty is because you are not pushing anything into it

you need something like

```
l1.push_back(msg);
```

as per the comments as well
in c++ you do not have to use C-style strings
instead of `strcpy()` you can just assign a string to the variable like:

std::string msg = " am fine";

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code:

1. You need to add the scope for `list`
2. The template argument has to be a type and not a value in your case

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string.h>

struct message
{
    int id;
    char mesg[100]; 
}; 

int main()    
{
    struct message Msg;
    Msg.id=111;
    strcpy(Msg.mesg," am fine");
    std::list<message*> l1;
}
```